# NPM Warning No description and No repository field

Tags: npm, cron, newman

I want to use newman for generate reporter in type CSV. When I run the command to **install sudo npm install csv**

It show warning message like this

```
npm WARN mycomputer@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN mycomputer@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ csv@5.3.2
updated 1 package and audited 369 packages in 1.785s

2 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

I don't know how to fix it, please help

Comment: The warnings just indicate that your `package.json` has empty or missing [`description`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#description-1) and [`repository`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#repository) fields. It won't stop it from working. To get rid of the warnings just add those fields to your `package.json` file.

Comment: I think is answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58972251/what-does-x-packages-are-looking-for-funding-mean-when-running-npm-install)

Answer (score 2):

You need to amend your parkage.json file and add

```
"description": "",
"repository": {
},
```

and you can specify the following for repo

```
"type": "git",
"url": "https://github.com/[parkage].git"
```