# How do I block advertising in npm?

Tags: javascript, npm

When I run various npm commands, the console output is filled with ads for various projects and people. I'm a prolific open source contributor, but console output for a tool is not a good place for advertising.

```
Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!

The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon:
> https://opencollective.com/core-js
> https://www.patreon.com/zloirock

Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)

...
...

Thank you for using husky!
If you rely on this package, please consider supporting our open collective:
> https://opencollective.com/husky/donate
```

That's around 11 lines of output, colorised to grab my attention, when I'm looking for warnings or errors.

**How do I block ads in npm?**

Comment: I don't know the answer but have some good news for you https://www.infoq.com/news/2019/08/npm-bans-package-ads/

Comment: Since that mechanism is supposed to be used for any possibly relevant message or warning and there's no specific "ads" type message, you can either block all output (maybe not a good idea) or try to get the package author to remove that arguably annoying message, like any other unnecessary code.

Comment: I don't think there's anything native that would work for all NPM packages, NPM has banned this practice so maybe just report them?

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#loglevel

Comment: How did somebody vote to close this as opinion-based?

Comment: @ParthRaval The packages (and the OPEN_SOURCE_CONTRIBUTOR environment variable mentioned) mentioned in your article would make for a good answer.

Comment: @ParthRaval - ditto what _@mikemaccana_ suggests. You should change your comment into a formal answer. Even if you just quote the last two paragraphs from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/funding#how-can-i-disable-this) it would suffice as a good answer.

Comment: @RobC & `@mikemaccana`, Thank you, brothers, for your support & help.

Comment: MSFT has started doing this in the console window for VS Code too when using older versions of languages like PowerShell. Very annoying.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58972251/what-does-x-packages-are-looking-for-funding-mean-when-running-npm-install

Answer (score 6):

You can [remove ads using the `funding` package](https://github.com/feross/funding#how-can-i-disable-this) by adding an environment variable:

```
OPEN_SOURCE_CONTRIBUTOR=true
```

Some packages that use [opencollective-postinstall](https://github.com/opencollective/opencollective-postinstall) need their own command instead:

```
DISABLE_OPENCOLLECTIVE=true
```

Answer (score 0):

for the opencollective

`OPENCOLLECTIVE_HIDE=true`

did the trick for me, more optins see https://github.com/nuxt/opencollective#disable-message for more disabling options

Comment: That same link also mentions `DISABLE_OPENCOLLECTIVE`.

Comment: didn't work for me; `DISABLE_OPENCOLLECTIVE` seems to affect only `opencollective-postinstall` script as stated on that link

Comment: Sorry I can't see it - what link (can you write the URL) says that?