# how to fix and disable funding in mongoose library using npm?

Tags: node.js, npm, mongoose

I'm trying to create a MERN app. however after installing required packages. i have run my code however i'm getting  a weird error where one package(mongoose.js) is asking for funding in my terminal.

Is anyone knows how can i fix this problem? i have attached the error screenshot for reference any help would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That isn't an error, and it can be safely ignored. The creators of Mongoose have registered with NPM that they are looking for funding, and it is providing you a link if you want to contribute to their development.

See [What does 'x packages are looking for funding' mean when running `npm install`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58972251/what-does-x-packages-are-looking-for-funding-mean-when-running-npm-install)

Answer (score 0):

It's not actually an error. It's just that `npm` is reminding you that some packages you are using are looking for funding.

NPM packages are free, but there are people who work really hard behind, again for free, to maintain them.

So let's not deny them the right to look for funding to sustain their works :p

Comment: i would be like to see these things on website or other website rather than terminal. when i'm working on terminal i will expect logs related to my code not a advertisement.