# How to eliminate funding and ad noise from the npm build log?

Tags: javascript, npm

I've recently noticed that whenever I run an npm build the build log is full of ads and funding links. How can I clean my `npm` build log so that I won't see these?

Comment: Such packages violate [npm's Terms of Service](https://www.npmjs.com/policies/open-source-terms#commercial-content): "*These kinds of commercial content generally aren't acceptable: [...] Packages that display ads at runtime, on installation, or at other stages of the software development lifecycle, such as via npm scripts.*"

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58972251/what-does-x-packages-are-looking-for-funding-mean-when-running-npm-install