# while running npx create-react-app it shows packages are looking for funding

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

I want to run my first react app
I have installed node 
I have installed react globally using `npm install -g create-react-app`
but when i want to create react app using npx this happens

```
C:\Users\deep>npm install -g create-react-app
C:\Users\deep\AppData\Roaming\npm\create-react-app -> C:\Users\deep\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\index.js
+ create-react-app@3.4.1
updated 1 package in 14.608s

C:\Users\deep>cd Desktop

C:\Users\deep\Desktop>cd lets go

C:\Users\deep\Desktop\lets go>npx create-react-app myfirstreact

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\deep\Desktop\lets go\myfirstreact.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall C:\Users\deep\Desktop\lets go\myfirstreact\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js@3.6.5 postinstall C:\Users\deep\Desktop\lets go\myfirstreact\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js-pure@3.6.5 postinstall C:\Users\deep\Desktop\lets go\myfirstreact\node_modules\core-js-pure
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

+ react-scripts@3.4.1
+ react-dom@16.13.1
+ cra-template@1.0.3
+ react@16.13.1
added 1627 packages from 752 contributors in 367.744s

59 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
```

How should I run my first react app?

Comment: Just do `npm run start`, you have successfully set it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome on Stack Overflow.

You should fully read the Getting Started section on ReactJS website which is really complete. https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html

By the way,

`npx create-react-app mon-app` is used to create ReactJS project.

`npm start` is used to "launch" the project.

Based on [What does 'x packages are looking for funding' mean when running `npm install`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58972251/what-does-x-packages-are-looking-for-funding-mean-when-running-npm-install#:~:text=When%20you%20run%20%22npm%20fund,you%20can%20send%20them%20money). or [What does 'x packages are looking for funding' mean when running `npm install`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58972251/what-does-x-packages-are-looking-for-funding-mean-when-running-npm-install)
The funding alert means that some packages that you've installed need some fund (MONEY)

*Note: Avoid folder/file name with space that could avoid you some error in the future.*

Answer (score 0):

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Use this command to have folders created.

Comment: used it same thing happened

Comment: Then run " npm start"