# I am getting npm fund warnings when I am trying to install Angular packages:

Tags: node.js, angularjs, angular-cli, npm-install

I am getting npm warnings when I am trying to install packages:

changed 280 packages, and audited 280 packages in 2m

31 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

After this warning I have given command npm fund then I got My system name. I didn't understand.
Please anyone helpme how to solve this issue and how to complete Angular cli installation.

Comment: Duplicate of [What does 'x packages are looking for funding' mean when running \`npm install\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58972251/what-does-x-packages-are-looking-for-funding-mean-when-running-npm-install)

Comment: There is no problem with your installation, the fund errors came  from packages asking you to donate to maintain their package. In short term: donationware

Answer (score 2):

**npm fund** listes all dependencies to which its owners are seeking funds (or moneys) to maintain the development of that dependency. When you execute **npm fund** without arguments, then all installed dependencies on your project (That is direct dependencies and dependencies dependencies) which are looking for funds will be listed.

More info on: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-fund

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of the `npm fund` warnings permanently with the `npm config set fund false` command. It sets the  funds flag in your `.npmrc` file to `funds=false`

[a sample screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzitx.png)

Comment: A better explanation and more detailed answers are available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58972251/what-does-x-packages-are-looking-for-funding-mean-when-running-npm-install?noredirect=1&lq=1)