# when i install npm install @react-navigation/native than i face this issues

Tags: react-native

added 11 packages, and audited 1201 packages in 9s

79 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

47 vulnerabilities (11 moderate, 36 high)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force

Comment: So what are the vulnerabilities?

Answer (score 0):

It's basically a list of the modules you have that need contributions or donations of money to their projects and which list websites where you can enter a credit card to help pay for them.

For more details read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58972251/what-does-x-packages-are-looking-for-funding-mean-when-running-npm-install)

Comment: i am create new react native project and than i install navigation than gate this

Comment: Yeah but it's not compulsory to give funds, It will show you this message whenever you do npm install 'package name'. It's because the package you are using need fund if you can give it's good otherwise ignore it.

Comment: I hope this helps.