# NPM Error Message: I am getting an error message installing swagger

Tags: node.js, npm, swagger

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Install the latest PowerShell for new features and improvements! 

 npm install -g swagger
npm WARN deprecated formidable@1.2.6: Please upgrade to latest, formidable@v2 or formidable@v3! Check these notes: 
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated formidable@1.0.17: Please upgrade to latest, formidable@v2 or formidable@v3! Check these notes:
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated to-iso-string@0.0.2: to-iso-string has been deprecated, use @segment/to-iso-string instead.
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.1: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN deprecated URIjs@1.16.1: package renamed to "urijs" (lower-case), please update accordingly
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.3.0: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN deprecated superagent@3.8.3: Please upgrade to v7.0.2+ of superagent.  We have fixed numerous issues with streams, form-data, attach(), filesystem
 errors not bubbling up (ENOENT on attach()), and all tests are now passing.  See the releases tab for more information at <https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/releases>.
npm WARN deprecated superagent@1.8.5: Please upgrade to v7.0.2+ of superagent.  We have fixed numerous issues with streams, form-data, attach(), filesystem
 errors not bubbling up (ENOENT on attach()), and all tests are now passing.  See the releases tab for more information at <https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/releases>.
npm WARN deprecated jade@0.26.3: Jade has been renamed to pug, please install the latest version of pug instead of jade
npm WARN deprecated swagger-editor@2.10.5: No longer maintained, please upgrade to swagger-editor@3.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.4 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engin
e whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.

added 453 packages, and audited 454 packages in 16s

8 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

30 vulnerabilities (1 low, 11 moderate, 12 high, 6 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
 npm install express

up to date, audited 219 packages in 987ms

23 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58972251/what-does-x-packages-are-looking-for-funding-mean-when-running-npm-install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are not errors but warnings that won't affect your working and how swagger behaves. They just notify the user who might be the maker of the package to update their package as the packages their package depends upon have been deprecated and may have bugs

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it installed ok but as per @Arnav's answer it is just highlighting the deprecated packages.

I ran into a similar issue but the install was ultimately failing with `ERR!` messages when installing locally in the project.

Instead I installed globally with `npm i -g swagger-editor` which works fine.